# Finding a high power of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given that

$A=PDP^{-1}$

where P is invertible, and given

$D=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$

find $A^{2017}$

I do not know P so I can't find the exact answer, but I am supposed to find it in terms of A or I (a power of 2 multiplied by either A or I?)

I know that this is related to eigenvalues, more specifically:

$A^{2017}=PD^{2017}P^{-1}$

But I am not sure how to proceed...

Comment: $D^{2017} = \begin{pmatrix}2^{2017} & 0 \\ 0 & (-2)^{2017}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Hint: Compute $A^2$. with the formula $A=PDP^{-1}$

Comment: What about $D^{2018}$ ?

Comment: I understand how to do D in the power of 2017, but how do I reflect on A, given that I don't know what P is ?

Comment: $A$ is just any matrix with eigenvalues $2$ and $-2$. They can all be written this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that for all $n$: $$A^n = PD^n P^{-1}$$ by induction

$n=1$ is by definition true. Suppose it holds for $n$, then $$A^{n+1} = (A^n)A = \text{ (induction hypothesis) } (PD^n P^{-1})A = \\
P D^n P^{-1} P D P^{-1}= PD^n D P^{-1} = PD^{n+1}P^{-1}$$

so it holds for $n+1$ too.

Now use that for a diagonal matrix $$D=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b
\end{pmatrix}$$

we have $$D^n=\begin{pmatrix} a^n & 0 \\ 0 & b^n
\end{pmatrix}$$

which can also be shown by induction.

In your specific case, $$A^{2017} = P \begin{pmatrix} 2^{2017} & 0 \\ 0 & -2^{2017}
\end{pmatrix} P^{-1} =  P\left( 2^{2016}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}\right)P^{-1} =\\
 2^{2016}(P\begin{pmatrix}2 &0\\ 0 &-2\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}) = 2^{2016}A$$

I think.

Comment: I am looking to find out if A in the power of 2017 is equal to 2 in the power of 2017 multiplied by A or I, or is it 0, A, I ?

Comment: @Jankel, $2^{2016}$ is what I get.

Comment: Thank you, with your latest edition I got it :-)